# Get a value of a field on the referenced node from a paragraph

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I have a field on a node: field_`generic_partner_prod_ref` which is an entity reference. If I want to access field value on the referenced node - I'll do it like this in the twig template:

```
node.field_generic_partner_prod_ref.entity.field_page_title.value
```

Now I want to use the same entity reference field in a paragraph and in my paragraph twig template access values on the referenced node - but I cant get it to work.

In the twig I can print the node like this: `{{ content.field_generic_partner_prod_ref }}` but no way I can access its `field_page_title`.

### Edit

The node I reference in my paragraph has the following fields: `field_image` - `field_page_title`. I would like to access value of these field directly in my twig template for my paragraph. Just like you can do with reference fields in a node twig template (see above).

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried

Comment: So what is `content`? What error are you getting? If you are including a template you just should be able to access `node` like you did in the first part

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author)*.

Here is what I ended up doing:
To get the field_page_title:
`{{ content.field_generic_partner_prod_ref[0]['#node'].field_page_title.value }}`

And to get the image on the referenced node:
`<img alt="{{ content.field_generic_partner_prod_ref[0]['#node'].field_image.get(0).alt }}" src="{{ content.field_generic_partner_prod_ref[0]['#node'].field_image.entity.fileuri|image_style('crop_simple') }}" title="{{ content.field_generic_partner_prod_ref[0]['#node'].field_image.get(0).title }}">`